# Problem with dimensions of Meshs when using Curves in Geometry Nodes or Modifier Array

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

All is in this image ! Thanks !
[image: Setup of the problem]

Comment: Of course it's normal in this case that global and local orientation are the same. When you apply the _Geometry Nodes_ modifier, you create a **single object** which has only one location, rotation, scale - and I would guess if you did no translations on it in _Object Mode_, it is aligned with the global orientation. Now, it may be consisting of separate meshes in _Edit Mode_, but it is only one object. Separating it by loose parts will create multiple objects, but they all inherit location, rotation and scale from the single object they were before.

Comment: Separating it will not automatically "try" to find out which orientation they could have and assign a matching rotation. This could work on simple cubes, but what about complex meshes? Instead of cubes you could have instanced spheres... or monkeys or anything else. For simple setups like this, if you need them separately afterwards and with correct orientation anyway, why bother with _Geometry Nodes_? Why not create a cube, move it off the world center, set the pivot point to 3D cursor, duplicate and rotate a few times? Then each cube will have its own translations.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please avoid text written inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be serarched for nor readily found by anyone looking for solutions in the future. Updates are difficult because it can't be easily edited in case of mistakes, nor updated in case of future changes. It doesn't follow the fonts and style of the website automatically, and doesn't work with screen readers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your messages. My post is a simplification of a scene with hundreds of Cubes (dominos) stacked along a spiral. Your solution would not work in this case, no ?